# apache - 403 forbidden

Tags: apache2

So I am trying to upload my files to a local apache on my Ubuntu Server. I installed apache2 and I am now getting 403 forbidden all the time.

I have been searching and looking for some answers as to why on stackoverflow and elsewhere so far, it has yielded no results.

Files in /etc/apache2 is: apache2.conf (this is big), evvars, magic, ports.conf and httpd.conf (this one was empty, nothing inside it).

Also once I have fixed this, a bit off-topic, but can I change it so that instead of typing the local ip-address or localhost so that I could type something like mysite.local/index.php?

Comment: Add the last 10 lines of your error.log

Comment: it says the date and then error and client then (13) Permission denied: access to "*dir*/file.php" denied. And it says the same except "File does not exists" this is repeated over and over.

Comment: The user apache user is under is a variable it says like ${APACHE_RUN_USER} and ls -l says linuxuser:linuxuser on the directory. it says only drwx followed by alot of dashes (sorry its on another virtual machine, can't copy. all files/folders within the directory has the same linuxuser:linuxuser.

Comment: it says www-data, I will try changing ownership to that user now. Ok so the owner of the dir is www-data:linuxuser but I still can't access it from my main computer. (403)

Comment: @rekire Do you have any thoughts about what can be wrong?

Comment: I think I've got it now yeah, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I guess right than your directory you are trying to access are accessable from the web.

You need a [`<Directory>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory) directive which allows the apache to access that directory:

```
<Directory /your/path>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from All
</Directory>
```

It is normal that the `httpd.conf` is empty. It is deprecated so you should not use it.

If you use linux also check that the user of your apache can access that directory:
The user is normally defined in the `/etc/apache2/envvars` file in a line like `export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data`. So if the apache runs under the user `www-data` the directory should be accessable by the user `www-data` or maybe better directly own that directory/files.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue after uploading static folders onto the apache document folder. But some of the files cannot be accessed in browsers with a 403 error.

After checking and fixing the file permission and the httpd.conf file mentioned by @rekire, the issue persisted.

At last, I read the post at http://www.petefreitag.com/item/793.cfm and did the following:

`chcon -R --reference=/var/www /path/to/webroot`

Then the issue was resolved.

I was using a CentOS server.